# Making UITextfield accessible in a Customised UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios-ui-automation

I have a UITextfield which is a subview of a UITableViewCell. I have customised the UITableViewCell, where I define the UITextField as a property. In the customised class, I override the UIAccessibilityContainer protocol methods.

However I am unable to set the textfields in my test script. This may be because the UIATableCell recognises its' children as UIAElements and not specifically UIATextFields. I am unable to perform to use the element as receiver for the method setValue.

[image]

It seems that the trait setting modulates how UIATableCell recognises its' children. However from the apple docs, a UITextField is best described as having either the UIAccessibilityTraitAllowsDirectInteraction or the UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable. Neither of these help.

As far as I can tell, I have set the visibility hierachy correctly.

```
   [self.contentView addSubview:self.aTextField];

   for (UIView *eachView in self.subviews) {
        [eachView  setIsAccessibilityElement:NO];

    }

    [ self.aTextField setIsAccessibilityElement:YES];
    [ self.aTextField setAccessibilityLabel:@"textFieldOnCell"];
    [self.contentView setAccessibilityElementsHidden:NO];
```

Have I missed a step in making a UITextField accessible in a customised UITableViewCell ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We noticed this problem and [worked around it in Illuminator](https://github.com/paypal/Illuminator/blob/master/docs/Extensions.md#forcing-an-element-to-take-input).

The basic idea is to tap the parent element (which should force the keyboard to appear) then use they keyboard to type the desired string.